# i cannot get PowerShell to add the LogName to the csv

Tags: csv, powershell, export-to-csv, invoke-command

I cannot get PowerShell to add the LogName to the csv. I am running this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server -Credential $cred -Authentication Default -ScriptBlock { 
    Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error | 
        Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Site,TimeGenerated, EventID, Message, Source, EntryType
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:/output.csv
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `| export-csv` should be inside the scriptblock.

Comment: If i did that, it would be stored on the server, which i dont want, i need it stored locally

Comment: Are you just looking to get "System" added to each entry under its own column? Since you are only looking at system logs would that not be assumed? `Select-Object -Property PSComputerName,Site,TimeGenerated, EventID, Message, Source, EntryType, @{name="LogName";expression={"System"}}`

Comment: You can use  " | Export-Csv -Path Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\servername\share\output.csv" inside the scriptblock.

Comment: well I can't test `Invoke-Command` with `| export-csv` on my workstation because we didn't set up WinRM in our company, but to me it seems confusing because you don't have anything to export to a csv, if you don't use it inside the scriptblock.

Comment: You have the output of the command, that gets formatted and entered inside the CSV, i would like a column inside that csv that says the logname, for example i am getting the error logs from Application, i would like a logname column says Application for each entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt has the correct answer, after testing, his simple elegant method works perfectly. Thank you very much Matt. Much appreciated.